# Numpy: Insert value in 2d with 2 x 1d using fancy indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, indexing

I would like to fancy indexing given an array with row / column indices.
I have an array with column numbers (column index) which I have extracted from an `argmax` function,

With this, I would like to turn a zero 2D matrix into 1 (or True) for the index correspond to this column index. The rows goes from 0 to 4

Below are my trials and how I see the problem.

```
matrix1 = np.zeros((5, 10))
matrix2 = np.zeros((5, 10))
matrix3 = np.zeros((5, 10))
matrix4 = np.zeros((5, 10))
matrix5 = np.zeros((5, 10))

row = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
column = np.array([9,9,2,3,9,2,1,3,3,1])

matrix1[row, column] = 1
matrix2[[row, column]] = 1
matrix3[[row], [column]] = 1
matrix4[[[row], [column]]] = 1
matrix5[([row], [column])] = 1
```

How can I get it to work as intended?

**EDIT:**
In addition to above case, it exist a case when you only want 1 (one) value per row.

Comment: Try using `row[:,None]` as the row index, in other words use  a (5,1) for rows.  That will `broadcast` with the (10,) column to select a (5,10) array of elements.

Comment: Thanks, I will use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would sound a bit naive, but intuitively, I would find all possible combination of indices first.

```
matrix1 = np.zeros((5, 10))
row = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
column = np.array([9,9,2,3,9,2,1,3,3,1])

index = np.stack(np.meshgrid(row,column), -1).reshape(-1,2) 
matrix1[index[:,0], index[:,1]] = 1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I marked is an answer because it worked, but I kind of see the benefit of using a shorter version, 'row[:,None]' like @hpaulj suggests. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above case, it exist a case when you only want 1 (one) value per row. Extrapolating on answers from @hpaulj and @ashutosh-chapagain , such as solution would look like:

```
row = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
column = np.array([9,9,2,3,9])

matrix2[row[:,None], column[:,None]] = 1
```

and the result would look like this:

[image: fanzy idx one per row]